# Multiple Entries in a Journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am entering Contacts multiple times in a journey. The scenario is that a Contact can have multiple contracts and he should be sent renewal emails for each contract.

I have a Is_Renewed field in the Event DE. Now if one contract is renewed and another is not, I want to eject the contact corresponding to that renewed contract only. He should continue to receive emails for his other contracts though.

After a contract is renewed (Is_Renewed turns from False to True in the DE), then I am not able to catch that particular contact.
So let's say there are 2 records for a Contact in the DE. Initially, both have Is_Renewed as 'False' .. Both enter the journey successfully. Now one contract gets renewed (so Is_Renewed becomes True for one record in the DE). Now I want to eject this one from the journey. But JB is not catching the update .. (I have tried Contact Data and Event Data both)

Is this a Journey Builder limitation? How can I work around it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, what you say makes sense. What is occuring in simple terms, is that the Event Source data "accompanies" the Contact through each Activity in the Interaction as they move through it. If you update a value in the Event Source Data Extension, then this is effectively ignored; Decision Split Activities will evaluate Event Source data based on the values when they were injected into the journey.

What you need to do is to create a separate Data Extension containing the `Is_Renewed` field and the Contract, then create a cardinal relationship for that Data Extension to the Contact Record.

For example, your Attribute Group could look something like this:

[image: contact record relationship]

*This assumes that a Population already exists for your Contacts, if it doesn't you will need to create one first.*

When the Contract changes, you will need to update the `Is_Renewed` field in the Contracts Data Extension.

Then in your Decision Split Activity, use the `Is_Renewed` field in the Contracts Attribute Set (Data Extension) to evaluate whether they should be ejected from the Interaction.

Comment: Hi Eliot, I think I didn't explain my problem clearly. I have updated the original question. Please help